How can i commit just my unity project scripts to git hub?
So my unity game project is now heavier than the 5 mb git hub allows. I tried uploading the entire project but now im just focusing in commiting the Scipts carpet of the project on GitHub. How can I do it?
I tried cloning a repo within the project but i dont think thats the correct way to do it.

5mb is pretty small .. did you mean 5GB? And also see the answer below .. not sure why it was downvoted but for sure you shouldn't commit the Library folder (among others) and large files into git

You need a git ignore file. This will not track the files generated by unity which do not need to be stored.
For unity, use this git ignore. This should be in the same folder as your (hidden) .git folder, and the same folder as your project files.

This will ignore all Unity generated files such as Library, Temp, Obj etc, as well as your IDE temp files too.
If you are still having propblems and have very large files (such as meshes or massive textures) then you can look into Git's large file system Git LFS.

For git LFS this might be a good start: .gitattributes
